# How to convert an Inkscape SVG file into a Microsoft Word drawing?

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, inkscape

How can I convert or insert an [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file to a Microsoft Word document?

Note: It has to be editable. The resulting exported PDF has selectable text.

Comment: Why `.doc` or `.pub`? `.pdf` would be more appropriate I think.

Comment: Its a requirement from my employer to be able to repurpose my resume. I'm editing the question since it has to be in doc. Its not preferable, but it is what it is. [Edit, the link to the resume was for an example of what it should look like in the word doc]

Comment: Do you have access to both Inkscape and Microsoft Word?

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. SVG is a graphic format, You could export it in any graphic format (let's say, as a GIF, PNG, JPG, BMP) and put it inside any Word document. It would be a graphic inside a .DOC document, the same way you would  do with any picture...

Comment: It has to be editable. The resulting exported PDF has selectable text.

Comment: @woliveirajr I'm working on an answer to retain the vectors/text.

Comment: @monksy : but it's a image or some text, typed in side inkscape, to be used as a text ???

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### To embed an Inkscape drawing into a Word document:

1. Open the file in Inkscape.

   [image: open]
2. Save the file as an **Enhanced Metafile** (`.emf`).

   [image: save as]
3. Be sure to **untick** `Convert text to paths`

   [image: text to paths]
4. **Insert** the `.emf` file as a **picture** in a Word document.

   [image: insert]
   [image: picture]

---

### To edit the drawing and text:

5. **Right-click** the picture and select `Edit Picture`.

   [image: edit]
6. **Click** `Yes` to convert to a drawing object.

   [image: object]
7. Tada!

   [image: complete]

Comment: EMF export is only supported on Windows: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.45#EMF_export

Comment: This works also for OpenOffice/LibreOffice Draw ODG files.  Thanks.

Comment: You can, if you want to import arbitrary SVG files platform-independent, [convert them online](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-emf)

Comment: Mac supports only wmf types, not emf. At least there is a solution.

Comment: Export to EMF worked in Inkscape-0.91 on Ubuntu-16.04/Linux.  (not MS-Windows-only feature now - may have been at the time of the prior comment.)

Answer (score 30):

### 2016 Update

> **[Note](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-2016-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)**: This feature is only available if you have an [Office 365 subscription](https://products.office.com/en-us/buy/compare-microsoft-office-products). If you are an Office 365 subscriber, make sure you
>   have the latest version of Office.

***Microsoft Word 2016 can now directly import SVG***:

1. Place your cursor where you'd like the image to be inserted.
2. Go to the **Insert** tab of the Ribbon.
3. Click **Pictures**

   [image]
4. Navigate to where the SVG file you wish to insert is located and
   select it. Click **Insert**.

**Source**: [**Insert SVG images in Microsoft Office**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-SVG-images-in-Microsoft-Office-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

What's particularly cool is that looking under the covers reveals that SVG is being stored natively within the OOXML.  This is much better for image quality preservation than importing to a raster format would be, and is more interoperable than EMF/WMF.

**Platforms**: SVG import unfortunately does not appear to be supported on the Mac platform or on Word Online as of this writing (August 2017).

### 2019 Update

SVG import is now supported on Mac, confirmed with an Office 365 subscription at least.

Comment: This does not work for me although I have the latest updates installed on my Word 2016 (64Bit).

Comment: I have Office 2016 64Bit (16.07668.7101). When I try to insert a SVG image I get the message: "An error occurred while importing this file.". I have Windows 10 and I did file a report on Feedback Hub App, the title is: Word 2016 does not Insert SVG images

Comment: @Devid, ever heard anything from them? I have Office 2016 on Windows 10, and my effort to import a SVG produces only a gray picture frame icon.

Comment: @katriel I have know the version 1707 (Build 8326.2073) of Office 2016. I tested it with this SVG image: https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg  and it works. I tested it by drag and drop.

Comment: According to the support.office.com article linked to in this answer - "This feature is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription".  I don't have an Office 365 subscription, so this doesn't work for me, even though I'm using Office Professional Plus 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: @DanielSchilling: Answer updated to point out the Office 365 subscription requirement.  Thank you.

Comment: best approach is to convert svgs to other image file formats using some online tool, for example like [this](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-jpg), worked for me

Comment: @DanielSchilling I also do not have an Office 365 subscription, but I am using 2016 ProPlus on Windows 10, and it is working. Perhaps you just hadn't received the update at the time?

Comment: FWIW SVG images work on the Mac version, but I have a subscription.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Confirmed.   Answer updated.  Thank you!

Comment: Any idea whether the fonts are embedded?  I like to use some very custom fonts in my GraphViz generated SVG, and would need to use Cairo if the fonts are not embedded.

Answer (score 4):

I am using word 2013 and thus I cannot import svg directly. However, LibreOffice is capable of doing that. I am using **LibreOffice 5** and I could import the svg file with

```
insert -> image -> choose your file
```

After that I just copied the imported svg from LibreOffice to Office. It seems like quality changed a bit, but for purposes that was fine.

Answer (score -2):

#### How to copy and paste a diagram from Inkscape into Microsoft Word

There is another simpler method which works all the time with all software, whatever age, including Mac OS.

1. Select the diagram in Inkscape. Click on/select Black Arrow at top left of the page. Click on corner of the diagram you wish to move, then pull the cursor around the diagram so a black box surrounds the diagram.
2. Select "Edit" → "Make a Bitmap copy". (This is halfway down the list with something like a camera next to it.) Click on it. A lot of dotted lines appear around your Inkscape diagram.

Now this is the trick.

3. Select "Edit" → "Copy". (Not "Make Bitmap copy". Doing this twice confuses some people.) Click.
4. Then open your Word document.
5. Click your cursor where you want to put the diagram.
6. In the Word document go to "Edit" → "Paste". Click.
7. Voila! Your diagram appears in the Word document with a box and handles around it.
8. Resize if necessary by selecting and dragging the bottom right corner, and move by selecting box and dragging.
9. Click. Box disappears. All done. Save.

Comment: The image looks blurred. Does word still handle the image as vector graphic ? How come Word 2016 still doesn't support SVG ?

Comment: @chmike The "Make Bitmap copy" step would give this away as exporting raster, not vector. I have no answer to your second question, even 3 years later.  :)

Answer (score -2):

Another solution is to use Gimp, it can read SVG files and export them in PNG format.

Comment: This would work, but will produce a rasterized image, and may not print well.