# How to open HTML file which contains SVG image in word

Tags: html, svg

I have a HTML page which contains  texts and graphs( in SVG) format. When i am trying to open the page in Microsoft MS word then i can see texts  but SVG images are not getting imported in MS word.

How can i open a HTML file which contains embedded SVG images in Microsoft word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Word does not natively support SVG.
You have to rasterize (save it to another format, for example jpeg) it with another tool before you can use it in Microsoft Word.

For an alternative solution you can take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/397644/inserting-svg-files-in-a-microsoft-word-document).

Comment: But the SVG image is embedded into HTML page , how can i save the image separately into another format (example jpeg).

I tried to change the extension of html file from .html to .svg or .jpeg and when tried to open the file in INKSCAPE but INKSACAPE cannot load the file...

Comment: I would advise you to test [openoffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) if that's the case. I know OpenOffice has support for SVG, but I'm not too sure about inlined content. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried Libreoffice , OpenOffice ..Both not working....