# Import GraphViz graph to Microsoft Word 14

Tags: microsoft-word, graphviz

I have created a GraphViz dot-file to visualize a data flow. I have to write a documentation using Microsoft Word and I'd like to include the graph in the document.

For some wired reason, MS Word is not able to import `SVG` files. Then, I generated a `.eps` file using

`dot -Teps plan.dot -o plan.eps`

But once imported into Word, the picture looks horrible.
I also tried to convert the `svg` to `wmf` using Inkscape. It also looked horrible.

Is there a clean way to generate a file using GraphViz that Word can read?

Comment: Can you save it as an `emf` instead? http://superuser.com/questions/397644/inserting-svg-files-in-a-microsoft-word-document

Comment: BTW, the EPS should still work OK, it is just not anti-aliased when rendering.  If you zoom in, you can see that the detail is there, and it will print nicely at full resolution.  But I can see where this is not sufficient if the main use is on-screen.

Comment: Late comment: I am using the vector image format [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) as output format of `GraphViz`. Then, I convert `svg` to Windows enhanced metafile [emf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) which can be imported to `Office` tools like `Word` and `Powerpoint`. The conversion from `svg` to `emf` can be accomplished [svg2emf](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/svg2emf).

Answer (score 0):

Exporting as .jpg or .png and both worked here with a simple example, as does .pdf, but that does not render well if you open the .docx using Windows Word (e.g. 2010). None of the individual objects (shapes/text) are editable, though.