# Inserting Inkscape SVG drawing with colour gradient fill into Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, svg

I am trying to plug a drawing in Inkscape SVG format into a .docx Word 2013 file.

Using the solution posted under [Inserting SVG files in a Microsoft Word document](https://superuser.com/questions/397644/inserting-svg-files-in-a-microsoft-word-document), I am not able to maintain the colour gradient fill inside rectangles. Contrary to this discussion, I don't have the requirement for an editable figure in Word 2013.

I tried another solution suggested by Microsoft, that consists of exporting the SVG file to PDF and then importing into Word 2013 via the function insert >> object (Text) >> insert from file. This however resulted in a grossly distorted import of my drawing.

Exporting the SVG file to PNG format resulted in a rather pixelated import into Word 2013.

In the end, I exported the figure to PDF and made a screen snapshot after which I pasted this into Word. This worked out best.

However, I consider the last solution rather messy (presumably, total loss of vector graphic scalability) and impractical for a large set of figures. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: "...PNG format resulted in a rather pixelated import..." : when exporting to PNG in Inkscape you can manually set the resolution and/or dpi to something more appropriate.

Comment: How do you do this? I know there are differences between Inkscape on Windows and Linux. Now, I am running Inkscape 0.48 on Win 7. When selecting Save As >> Cairo PNG there is no pop-up window allowing me to select the dpi, as occurs with some other formats

Comment: I just realized how you did this. You were selecting File >> Export to BMP, rather than File >> Save As. Any idea why this double implementation?

Comment: I don't know why there are two implementations. The Export option is certainly more flexible than the Save As option.

Comment: Save As creates a file that inkscape can edit directly.
Export creates a separate file which inkscape may not be able to edit.