# Converting word to pdf with svg inside, file provided

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, svg

I have already asked this question once, but cannot access the account to provide a download link. Here it is now: https://uploadfiles.io/x507b

I don't have any expensive adobe programmes or anything similar that isn't free, only Office is provided by my school.

I have to submit an essay in pdf format. I wrote it in Word and used an svg file there, now that those are supported. My output in the pdf needs to be an svg file too, but if I try to print it it ends up being not very sharp, so I think it ends up being an image. What solutions exist there?

I don't have any expensive adobe programmes or anything similar that isn't free, only Office is provided by my school.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: Similar question on Super User [link](https://superuser.com/questions/397644/inserting-svg-files-in-a-microsoft-word-document)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'File/Save As' and chose 'PDF', instead of using 'Print'.

If you prefer to use 'Print', go into the detail settings and set the image resolution higher, etc. there are dozens of settings in the typical print driver.

Comment: Microsoft's Export PDF/XPS is useless since it creates formulas as raster images... It can export .emf in a pdf though.